# Router "ghost" connections

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp

[image]
[image]

My **Linksys WRT54GS2 V1** has begun to display ghost wired connections in the last weeks. As you can see from the images I have nothing connected except for the power cable.

I have tried a **hard reset** and **factory defaults**, also leaving the router disconnected all night.

The DHCP list show no clients but the one I'm connecting from.

The problem this causes is **limited connectivity** for Wireless devices and **no connection** at all for wired connections. Only my wireless laptop can connect always, and a wired connection can connect sometimes.

After setting a mobile wifi configuration to **static** instead of **DHCP**, I managed to be able to connect that device. So I guess there's a problem with the **DHCP** of the router.

Comment: Maybe a drop of solder on one of the connectors? Have you tried opening it up and looking at the pins?

Comment: No I didn't try anything at hardware level. The router didn't fall or anything like that, so I was hoping for a software solution.

Comment: Huh. Faulty firmware? If it doesn't void your warranty, I'd open it up and see if there's a stray dollop of solder or something. 
Has it always been like this?

Comment: No, like I said it has been like this in the last weeks. I have this router for like 2 years now.

Comment: Could this be caused by a long dhcp lease time?

Comment: Link indicators are not affected by DHCP, but electrical polarity. 
Examine the ports carefully; a wire might have jumped its slot, creating a 'loopback' condition.  I notice you have a universal power supply:  If you've been running the router below its required voltage and amperage, it may have malfunctioned, possibly permanently.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get some wired RJ45 plugs.
2. Cut off the ends/cables and connect all the exposed wire ends together by twisting all of them. Hotglue to not impale yourself on the sharp wires afterwards.
3. Put one in each port that's not working properly. It will go 'blank', as expected of an empty port.
4. When they are all blank, restart and then feel free to connect computers in the remaining ports/use wireless.

Answer (score 0):

Since the hardware is out of warranty I suggest trying a different [firmware](http://dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_WRT54G2_v1.3_&_WRT54GS2_v1.0), if the problem still exists, then its a hardware level problem and cannot be solved by software.

There are two additional files on the firmware database at http://dd-wrt.com so be sure to search for your router for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already downloaded DD WRT packages for my router but, as it is an irreversible change, before trying that I was hoping for a less drastic solution.

Do you believe this kind of problem can be solved by changing the firmware?

Comment: @Veehmot - Based on the description you provided the current status of your router is that its pretty useless.  Since I can guarantee that DD-WRT is better then the stock firmware you have, what you have to lose is, what basically amounts to a broken router.  Please don't tell me this router is from 2003 because it doesn't even support 802.11n.